# Facebook API : Permission required to pull feeds on a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am confused with upgraded permission. Different people have different opinion with permissions. Please someone suggest me.

1. What are the permission required to pull likes count, reach count, engagement count **for a page**?
2. What are the permission required to pull likes count, comment count, share count on **a post mentioned on page**?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need just an valid access token, if the page/post is fully public you will be able to get number of likers & talking about for page and number of likes/comments/shares for posts.
This can be made by using the /feed edge for page-id and object_id for posts with different edges.